# Do we allow questions about how to set up a computer for certain games?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Specifically, do we allow questions about which ports are used by which games, to enable firewall administration, or would that belong elsewhere?

I vaguely remember questions of this nature being blocked, but can't find anything like this on any of the other stackexchange sites.

I've noticed that 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/what-port-does-the-settlers-of-catan-online-world-use-can-i-block-it-closed
Got closed, but that's partially beacuse he was asking how to block it? It seems strange that the way the question is asked could so dramatically affect whether it's allowed, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: I had a feeling you might've thought about that question. I wouldn't have closed it for being about blocking it (since, just like my NETGEAR example, the answer of what port is irrelevant to what you need the information for). I think people jumped on it as a question of "Can I block a specific port?", which the gaming portion is irrelevant. To me, the essence was "What is the port", which we can field, and "Can I block" is an accessory question that we can simply not address (and point out that it should be asked somewhere IT).

Comment: "Can I block a specific port?" is perfect for SuperUser, "What is the port" is for Gaming.

Comment: I saw that question.  I don't think it should have been closed.  The part of the question which pertains to gaming should have been answered and the OP gently reminded that SuperUser can help them if they needed help configuring a firewall.  imho

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say yes when it comes to defaults or standardized settings for ports. Whether you're trying to configure a netplay match with Hisoutensoku or trying to fix your firewall so others can join you in a game of Defense of the Ancients, this knowledge tends to be critical to actually playing a game. Often times it's already filled out when you look at the game's netplay menu, but that has rarely stopped a question being asked. Many net-gaming communities stick to the defaults because it is both well established and requires no extra fiddling.

And remember that "There is no default/standard port" is a very real answer, and should be given as such as opposed to being left as a comment and voting to close!

Any deviation from this is specific to the scenario and community in question, and any questions should be asked within that community. And expectedly so - you're being a part of that community in order to know that it is different!

Going past port settings and into general installation questions, I think that as long as there aren't any other outstanding issues with the question (I'm referring at least specifically to [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/adult-themed-gaming), which is still in debate), then we can allow these. They're not much different than the many questions we get about [[steam]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam), as long as we're still in the confines of the game. "How do I configure the port settings on a NETGEAR router", for example, would be off-topic (I think it fits on SU but you'd've to ask the SU people about that) because the fact you're configuring the router for gaming is irrelevant to the answer.