# Can we ask questions about internet browser games?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I noticed that people only talk about big games; Games that require you to download, or are really popular. Per example, take an **(.io)** game like **slither.io**. No one talks or posts about it. Can we ask about games that have been recently added **(*.io* or any broswer game)** (Take like **zombsroyale.io** per example) that bearly no one knows , or even *make/suggest* a **TAG** about it?

***NOTE:***

There is a question on meta about posting open-source games, but that is not my question. (D'ont mark it as a duplicate of that)

Comment: Hi GamerM. You can ask a question about any video game. People have asked about [tag:slither.io] too. Also: [I want to ask a question about a game which has no tag yet, how should I tag it?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/28182) - does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes Okay I was just confirming. Also, Is there a way to _suggest_ to add a tag?

Comment: You need [300 reputation points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to create tags yourself. As a workaround, Ask your question, state the game name clearly in full, and tag the question with anything (something related, like [tag:pc] usually helps), then leave a comment under your question asking if someone could add the appropriate tag for you. Someone will see it and edit it into your question for you :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can ask about any video game you like (as long as it is not [pirated](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7546/181240) or relating to [sexually explicit material/adult content](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/181240)). Browser games, console games, computer games, if it is a video game we will take it.

I can't guarantee how fast you might get an answer but you never know what other people are playing! (I myself have asked a lot of mobile Android game questions for stuff I was sure no one would know about and was pleasantly surprised to get an answer, and I know we have had other browser based stuff asked before!)

So ask away. If you can't make a tag, just comment like Robotnik mentioned and someone will get to it until you have enough rep to make them yourself.

Good luck!

Comment: To clarify: you can ask about *almost* any video game. There are rules against [adult content](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/181240) and [pirated games](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7546/181240).

Comment: @StevenVascellaro valid point, I didn't consider those when I answered.

Comment: Note, that the pirated part is about "how to pirate" or advocating for it, not about the game being pirated or not.

Comment: @Braiam - The 'Don't ask, don't tell' policy (sometimes called the 'Good Faith' argument) is that we assume you are playing the game 100% legally, i.e. we approach your question '*In Good Faith*'. For example, it's legal to make your own ROM dumps for backup/archival purposes, and to play your legally backed up game on an emulator, therefore we accept questions about emulation or about playing games on an emulator. But we don't accept questions about how to download ROMs, nor advocate the downloading of ROMs, or accept questions on how to use KeyGens, Cracks etc...

Answer (score 1):

We have questions about browser games.  E.g.

- [the-gold-factory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-gold-factory)
- [succubox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succubox)

Those are two browser games that I played recently.  They happen to be by the same author because I found the one through the other.  And I found one on this site because...someone asked a question about it.

Also

- [bloons-monkey-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloons-monkey-city)
- [bloons-td-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bloons-td-5)

are browser games.

I'm sure there are others.  These are ones that I personally played, so I knew what they were.

However, if no one is playing a game yet, you may not get answers quickly.

Arqade covers any (or almost any, perhaps I'm missing an exception) legal, non-porn game played on a computing device (e.g. a PC, console, or phone).  We do not cover games played on a physical board, with cards, or generally in-person.  We may cover some games that can be played both on a computer and in-person.  For example, [hearthstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearthstone) is within our remit; it is a card game but only played on a computer.

Answer (score -1):

They won't be disallowed.

The most basic game we have on record is probably the [kittens-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kittens-game).  Not only is this a browser game.  It is a JavaScript browser game.

However, this game have some rather interesting depth to it, so the questions are interesting too.